# Why the Stopwatch with react native makes the app running slow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building a simple quiz app with five questions, and I set up a stopwatch while the user is answering the questions.

Once the user starts answering the stopwatch starts and once he anwsered the last question the stopwatch stops.

The big issue is: As soon as the stopwatch starts the page is going slow.

When I answer the question is going slow. It takes 5 seconds at least to have the next question.

As soon as I press stop on the stopwatch (so the stopwatch is not running) the page works normally. it is not running slow.

Coudl you please tell what can I do to fix the issue?

I am new in react native so I don't exactly know what I should try to fix the issue.

I show you the code:

```
export default function Question () {
  const allQuestions = data;
  const [currentQuestionIndex, setCurrentQuestionIndex] = useState(0)
  const [currentOptionSelected, setCurrentOptionSelected] = useState(null);
  const [correctOption, setCorrectOption] = useState(null);
  const [isOptionsDisabled, setIsOptionsDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0)
  const [showNextButton, setShowNextButton] = useState(false)
  const [showScoreModal, setShowScoreModal] = useState(false)
  
  const [isStopwatchStart, setIsStopwatchStart] = useState(true);
  const [resetStopwatch, setResetStopwatch] = useState(false);


  const validateAnswer = (selectedOption) => {
    let correct_option = allQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]['correct_option'];
    setCurrentOptionSelected(selectedOption);
    setCorrectOption(correct_option);
    setIsOptionsDisabled(true);
    if(selectedOption==correct_option){
        // Set Score
        setScore(score+1)
    }
    // Show Next Button
    setShowNextButton(true)
  }

  const handdleNext = () => {
    if(currentQuestionIndex== allQuestions.length-1){
        //last Question
        //Show Score Modal
        setShowScoreModal(true)
    }else{
        setCurrentQuestionIndex(currentQuestionIndex+1);
        setCurrentOptionSelected(null);
        setCorrectOption(null);
        setIsOptionsDisabled(false);
        setShowNextButton(false);
    }
  }

  const restartQuiz = () => {
    setShowScoreModal(false);

    setCurrentQuestionIndex(0);
    setScore(0);

    setCurrentOptionSelected(null);   
    setCorrectOption(null);
    setIsOptionsDisabled(false);
    setShowNextButton(false);
  }

  const renderQuestion = () => {
    return (
        <View>
        {/* Question Counter */}
        <View style={styles.question}>
            <Text style={styles.textquestion}>{currentQuestionIndex+1}</Text>
            <Text style= {styles.total}>/ {allQuestions.length}</Text> 
        </View>

        {/* Question */}
        <Text style={styles.sizequestion}>{allQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]?.question}</Text>
    </View>
    )

  }

  const renderOption = () => {
    return (
        <View>
             {
                allQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]?.options.map(option => (
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.effect}
                    key={option}
                    onPress={()=> validateAnswer(option)}
                    disabled={isOptionsDisabled} 
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.optionquestion} > {option} </Text>

                    {/* Show Check or cross icon based on correct answer */}
                    {
                        option==correctOption ? (
                            <View>
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="check" style={styles.iconcheck} />

                            </View>
                        ): option == currentOptionSelected ? (
                            <View style={styles.designclose} >
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="close"  style={styles.closeicon} />
                            </View>
                        ) : null
                    }

                    </TouchableOpacity>
                ))
             }
                
            
        </View>
           
        
    )
  }

  const renderNextButton = () => {
    if(showNextButton){
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.next2} onPress={handdleNext} >
                <Text style={styles.designnext}>Next</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }else{
        return null
    }
  }

   /* StopTime */

   const StopTime = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.container2}>
           
            <View style={styles.sectionStyle}>
              <Stopwatch
                laps
                msecs
                start={isStopwatchStart}
                //To start
                reset={resetStopwatch}
                //To reset
                options={options}
                //options for the styling
                getTime={(time) => {
                //  console.log(time);
                }}
              />
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  setIsStopwatchStart(!isStopwatchStart);
                  setResetStopwatch(false);
                }}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                  {!isStopwatchStart ? 'START' : 'STOP'}
                </Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  setIsStopwatchStart(false);
                  setResetStopwatch(true);
                }}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>RESET</Text>
               </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );

   }

   /*  End of StopTime */


return (
   <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

    <StatusBar style={styles.barStyle} />

    <View style={styles.mainstyle}>
       

        {/*  Question */}
        {renderQuestion()}

        {/* Options */}
        {renderOption()}

        {/* Next Button */}
        {renderNextButton()}


        {/* Stoptime feature */}
          {StopTime()} 

        {/* Score Modal */}
        <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={showScoreModal}
        >
            <View style={styles.designresult} >

                <View style={styles.result} >
                    <Text style={styles.result2} > { score> (allQuestions.length/5) ? 'Congratulations!' : 'Oops!' } </Text>

                    <View style={styles.final} >
                    <Text style={styles.final2} > {score} </Text>
                    <Text> /{allQuestions.length} </Text>

                    

                    </View>
                    {/* Retry Quiz button */}

                     <Button title="Retry Quiz" style={styles.design2}   onPress={restartQuiz}> 
                       
                     {/* <Text style={styles.retrydesign} > Retry Quiz </Text> */}

                     </Button> 

                </View> 

            </View>
        </Modal>


       {/*  <StopTime/>  */}

    </View>

   </SafeAreaView>

    

)
```

Comment: If you can edit your question to include the relevant code it will help us better understand where the issue might be.

Comment: Hi @Stephen Gilboy thank you for your answer I put the all code to show you guys the issue